# stop event bubbling on gallery plugin

Tags: javascript, gallery

I'm trying to modify a Javascript code which is an gallery plugin. I added button for bootstrap model on Item main view. When I click it model open up but Content window close as it defines in plugin. I want to keep open the content section and disable the mouse cross style pointer on hover of modal button. Working demo is here.

http://216.244.79.226/testGrid/

I tried event.stopPropagation(); and other codes but nothing works. Anyone please help.

```
Plugin code
-------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    const MathUtils = {
        lineEq: (y2, y1, x2, x1, currentVal) => {
            // y = mx + b 
            var m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1), b = y1 - m * x1;
            return m * currentVal + b;
        },
        lerp: (a, b, n) =>  (1 - n) * a + n * b
    };

    // Window size
    let winsize;
    const calcWinsize = () => winsize = {width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight};
    calcWinsize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', calcWinsize);

    const getMousePos = (ev) => {
        let posx = 0;
        let posy = 0;
        if (!ev) ev = window.event;
        if (ev.pageX || ev.pageY) {
            posx = ev.pageX;
            posy = ev.pageY;
        }
        else if (ev.clientX || ev.clientY)  {
            posx = ev.clientX + body.scrollLeft + docEl.scrollLeft;
            posy = ev.clientY + body.scrollTop + docEl.scrollTop;
        }
        return {x: posx, y: posy};
    }
    // Track the mouse position
    let mousePos = {x: winsize.width/2, y: winsize.height/2};
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', ev => mousePos = getMousePos(ev));

    // Custom mouse cursor.
    class CursorFx {
        constructor(el) {
            this.DOM = {el: el};
            this.DOM.toggle = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.cursor__inner--circle');

            this.DOM.title = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.cursor__inner--text');
            this.bounds = {
                toggle: this.DOM.toggle.getBoundingClientRect(),
                title: this.DOM.title.getBoundingClientRect()
            };
            this.lastMousePos = {
                toggle: {x: mousePos.x - this.bounds.toggle.width/2, y: mousePos.y - this.bounds.toggle.height/2},
                title: {x: mousePos.x - this.bounds.title.width/2, y: mousePos.y - this.bounds.title.height/2}
            };
            this.lastScale = 1;
            this.lastOpacity = 1;
            requestAnimationFrame(() => this.render());
        }
        render() {
            // Mouse movement distance on the x-axis
            const diff = this.lastMousePos.toggle.x - (mousePos.x - this.bounds.toggle.width/2);
            // Check if mouse is on the right side of the viewport
            const rightSide = mousePos.x >= winsize.width/2;
            // Switch the side of the title element
            this.DOM.title.style.left = rightSide ? 'auto' : '30px';
            this.DOM.title.style.right = rightSide ? '30px' : 'auto';
            // The position of the title/toggle and the viewport side will determine the speed for both of these elements
            const lerpFactor = {
                toggle: rightSide ? diff < 0 ? 0.15 : 0.1 : diff < 0 ? 0.1 : 0.15,
                title: rightSide ? diff < 0 ? 0.1 : 0.15 : diff < 0 ? 0.15 : 0.1
            };
            // Update the mouse position values given the previous calculated lerp value
            this.lastMousePos.toggle.x = MathUtils.lerp(this.lastMousePos.toggle.x, mousePos.x - this.bounds.toggle.width/2, lerpFactor.toggle);
            this.lastMousePos.toggle.y = MathUtils.lerp(this.lastMousePos.toggle.y, mousePos.y - this.bounds.toggle.height/2, lerpFactor.toggle);
            this.lastMousePos.title.x = MathUtils.lerp(this.lastMousePos.title.x, mousePos.x - this.bounds.title.width/2, lerpFactor.title);
            this.lastMousePos.title.y = MathUtils.lerp(this.lastMousePos.title.y, mousePos.y - this.bounds.title.height/2, lerpFactor.title);
            // Also the scale and opacity values for the toggle
            this.lastScale = MathUtils.lerp(this.lastScale, 1, 0.15);
            this.lastOpacity = MathUtils.lerp(this.lastOpacity, 1, 0.1);
            // Apply the styles
            this.DOM.toggle.style.transform = `translateX(${(this.lastMousePos.toggle.x)}px) translateY(${this.lastMousePos.toggle.y}px) scale(${this.lastScale})`;
            this.DOM.toggle.style.opacity = this.lastOpacity;
            this.DOM.title.style.transform = `translateX(${(this.lastMousePos.title.x)}px) translateY(${this.lastMousePos.title.y}px)`;

            requestAnimationFrame(() => this.render());
        }
        setTitle(title) {
            // Sets the title content
            this.DOM.title.innerHTML = title;
        }
        click() {
            // Scales down and fades out the mouse toggle
            this.lastScale = .5;
            this.lastOpacity = 0;
        }
        toggle() {
            const isCircle = this.DOM.toggle.classList.contains('cursor__inner--circle');
            this.DOM.toggle.classList[isCircle ? 'remove' : 'add']('cursor__inner--circle');
            this.DOM.toggle.classList[isCircle ? 'add' : 'remove']('cursor__inner--cross');
            this.DOM.title.style.opacity = isCircle ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }

    const cursor = new CursorFx(document.querySelector('.cursor'));
    //const modalBtn = document.querySelector('#videoBtn');

    class Grid {
        constructor(el) {
            this.DOM = {el: el};
            // The grid element
            this.DOM.grid = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.grid');
            // Thr grid items
            this.DOM.items = [...this.DOM.grid.children];
            // totla number of grid items
            this.itemsTotal = this.DOM.items.length;
            // The content element ("behind" the grid)
            this.DOM.content = document.querySelector('.content');
            this.DOM.contentVideo = document.querySelector('.content-video');
            this.DOM.modalBtn = document.querySelector('#videoBtn');
            this.DOM.contentTitle = this.DOM.content.querySelector('.content__title');
            // Calculate heights of both the grid wrap and the grid, and also:
            // . the difference between them (then used for the grid/mousemove translation)
            // . the number of rows/columns 
            this.calculateSize();
            // The grid will be initially translated so it is in the center
            this.gridTranslation = {x: 0, y: -1*this.extraHeight/2};
            // Linear interpolation easing percentage (for the grid movement on mouse move)
            this.lerpFactor = 0.04;
            this.initEvents();
            requestAnimationFrame(() => this.render());
        }
        calculateSize() {
            // The height of the grid wrap
            this.height = this.DOM.el.offsetHeight;
            // The difference between the height of the grid wrap and the height of the grid. This is the amount we can translate the grid
            this.extraHeight = this.DOM.grid.offsetHeight - this.height;
            // Number of grid columns. The CSS variable --cell-number gives us the number of rows
            this.columns = this.itemsTotal/getComputedStyle(this.DOM.grid).getPropertyValue('--cell-number');
            // The animejs stagger function needs an array [cols,rows]
            this.gridDef = [this.columns, this.itemsTotal/this.columns];
        }
        initEvents() {
            // Window resize event 
            // The lerpFactor will change to 1 so theres no delay when translating the grid (or we would see the gaps on the top and bottom)
            window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                this.lerpFactor = 1;
                // Recalculate..
                this.calculateSize();
                this.columns = this.itemsTotal/getComputedStyle(this.DOM.grid).getPropertyValue('--cell-number');
                clearTimeout(this.resizeTimer);
                this.resizeTimer = setTimeout(() => this.lerpFactor = 0.04, 250);
            });

            this.DOM.items.forEach((item, pos) => {
                // The item's title.
                const title = item.dataset.title;
                // Show the title next to the cursor.
                item.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => cursor.setTitle(title));
                item.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    // Position of the clicked item
                    this.pos = pos;
                    this.title = title;
                    // Start the effect and show the content behind
                    this.showContent();
                    // Force to show the title next to the cursor (it might not update because of the grid animation - the item under the mouse can be a different one than the one the user moved the mouse to)
                    cursor.setTitle(title);
                });           

            });                
            // Show back the grid.
            this.DOM.content.addEventListener('click', () => this.showGrid());
        }
        // This is where the main grid effect takes place
        // Animates the boxes out and reveals the content "behind"
        showContent() {
            if ( this.isAnimating ) {
                return false;
            }

            this.isAnimating = true;
            // Set the content background image and title
            this.DOM.content.style.backgroundImage = this.DOM.items[this.pos].querySelector('.grid__item-inner').style.backgroundImage.replace(/img/g, 'img/large');
            //this.DOM.contentVideo.setAttribute.src = this.DOM.items[this.pos].querySelector('.grid__item-inner').setAttribute('src', /img/g, 'img/video');
            this.DOM.contentVideo.src = this.DOM.items[this.pos].querySelector('.grid__item-inner').dataset.title.replace(/img/g, 'img');
            this.DOM.contentTitle.innerHTML = this.title;
            //this.DOM.content.modalBtn = return false;

            // Scales down and fades out the mouse toggle
            cursor.click();
            cursor.toggle();

            this.animation = anime({
                targets: this.DOM.items,
                duration: 20,
                easing: 'easeOutQuad',
                opacity: 0,
                delay: anime.stagger(70, {grid: this.gridDef, from: this.pos})                
            });
            this.animation.finished.then(() => {
                // Pointer events class
                this.DOM.el.classList.add('grid-wrap--hidden');
                this.isAnimating = false;
            });            

            // Animates the title
            anime({
                targets: this.DOM.contentTitle,
                duration: 1700,
                delay: 200,
                easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                opacity: [0,1],
                translateY: [50,0]
            });           
            console.log('Function 1');

        }

        showGrid() {
            if ( this.isAnimating ) {
                return false;
            }       

            this.isAnimating = true;
            cursor.click();
            cursor.toggle();
            this.DOM.el.classList.remove('grid-wrap--hidden');
            // Could have used the reverse() but there seems to be a bug (glitch)..
            this.animation = anime({
                targets: this.DOM.items,
                duration: 20,
                easing: 'easeOutQuad',
                opacity: [0,1],
                delay: anime.stagger(70, {grid: this.gridDef, from: this.pos, direction: 'reverse'})
            });
            this.animation.finished.then(() => this.isAnimating = false);
            console.log('Function 2');
        }


        // Translate the grid when moving the mouse
        render() {
            // The translation will be either 0 or -1*this.extraHeight depending on the position of the mouse on the y-axis
            this.gridTranslation.y = MathUtils.lerp(this.gridTranslation.y, Math.min(Math.max(MathUtils.lineEq(-1*this.extraHeight, 0, this.height-this.height*.1, this.height*.1, mousePos.y), -1*this.extraHeight),0), this.lerpFactor);
            this.DOM.grid.style.transform = `translateY(${this.gridTranslation.y}px)`; 
            requestAnimationFrame(() => this.render());
        }
    }

    // Initialize the grid
    new Grid(document.querySelector('.grid-wrap'));

    // Preload all the images in the page
    imagesLoaded(document.querySelectorAll('.grid__item-inner, img'), {background: true}, () => document.body.classList.remove('loading'));
}

HTML code
-------------------------------------------------------------------

<body class="demo-1 loading">
        <!-- we are "preloading" the images in this hard-coded way; this should be done properly in a project, i.e. on click load -->
        <div class="hidden">
            <img src="img/large/1.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/2.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/3.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/4.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/5.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/6.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/7.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/8.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/9.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/10.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/11.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/12.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/13.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/14.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/15.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/16.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/17.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/18.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/19.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/20.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/large/21.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <main>
            <div class="content">

                <div class="container" id="videoCont">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                            <h2 class="content__title">Yerevan</h2>     
                            <button type="button" id="videoBtn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">
                                Launch demo modal
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                                <video class="content-video" width="320" height="240" controls>
                                    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="grid-wrap">
                <div class="grid">
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="London"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video1.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/1.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Yerevan"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video2.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/2.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Paris"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video3.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/3.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Madrid"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video4.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/4.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Moscow"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video5.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/5.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Lagos"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video6.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/6.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Dublin"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video7.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/7.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Bangkok"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video8.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/8.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Luanda"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video9.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/9.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Buenos Aires"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video10.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/10.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Berlin"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video11.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/11.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Vienna"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video12.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/12.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Minsk"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video13.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/13.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Brussels"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video14.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/14.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Lisbon"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video15.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/15.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Porto-Novo"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video16.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/16.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Sofia"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video17.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/17.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Phnom Penh"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video18.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/18.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Ottawa"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video19.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/19.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Praia"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video20.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/20.jpg)"></div></div>
                    <div class="grid__item" data-title="Bogota"><div class="grid__item-inner" data-title="img/video/video21.mp4" style="background-image:url(img/21.jpg)"></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <div class="cursor">
            <div class="cursor__inner cursor__inner--circle"></div>
            <span class="cursor__inner cursor__inner--text">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>


    <script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/demo1.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop immediate propagation and default behaviour. You can try following code

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I tried this but it preventing modal from opening. Seems like button don't have any event.